# DIV within DIV That has Overflow:hidden?

Tags: css

A bit of head scratching going on here, so any pointers would be much appreciated!

I have a header div that has the property overflow:hidden.  On the left of this header is the page title, and on the right a number of images.  This works perfectly well and everything shows as it should.

However, I now need to wrap these images around div tags (they will become clickable, and updated via Ajax - so I need to define the postback div for each image).  As mentioned, without wrapping the image around a div tag, they show fine.  However, as soon as I add the div tags, they disappear (though still show in the page source).  The div tags take the simple form of  and no styling is associated with them.

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but for the life of me it's totally bypassing me right now!

Thanks :-)

Comment: It's on a local server at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: can you just copy in some code, then? what do you mean by "wrap images around div tags"?

Comment: If you want to make images clickable, you dont' wrap the images around a div, you more put the images in an a:
<a href='display.html'><img src='img.jpg' /></a>
Or for javascript things:
<img src='img.jpg' onclick='alert("hello")' />

Comment: Sorry, I meant wrap div tags around the images (not vice-versa as I originally wrote).  The reason for doing this is so that when the images are clicked, the postback (which will also be an image) returns in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit unclear for me, any way if i understood your question

If you need to have click event you can use `asp:ImageButton` to hold the image.
if you really need to use `div`

```
<div class="header"> // this is the one with overflow hiddden
<div class="left"> // this div holds the page title ; float:left
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="right"> // this div to hold the divs which contain images
                    // if all your images are same height set the same height to this div and float:right
    <div class="image"> // this div holds the image; make float:left set height and width
        <img/>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img />
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What's an `asp:ImageButton`? (Rhetorical question. There's nothing to hint this question has anything to do with ASP.NET)